# Is char array a poor man's dictionary?

Tags: c#, arrays, ascii

I'm "self-taught" so I sometimes have trouble getting some concepts.

So lets say that in C#/Java I have a char array. I also have a separate int array.

What I don't get is how and why are my char and int arrays "smart" enough so that when I iterate over chars I can update the count of observed characters with incrementing, like it's some sort of dictionary?

Why is this working?

I am sorry for my wording, I don't know how to explain exactly how bewildering this is to me.

What other good uses can I put this to, other that comparing strings for permutation?

```
public static bool isPermutation(string s1, string s2)
    {
        if (s1.Length != s2.Length)
        {
            return false;
        }

        int[] letters = new int[128];

        var first = s1.ToCharArray();
        var second = s2.ToCharArray();


        foreach (int c in first)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c);
            Console.WriteLine(letters[c]);
            letters[c]++;
        }
//etc...
```

Comment: A char array is a "list" of characters, a dictionary is a "list" of key-value pairs where the key is hashed. Those are completely different data structures, and using 2 independent lists doesn't get even close to being equal to a dictionary

Comment: I was just surprised that to get an ASCII table, with keys being ASCII characters and values being their occurences, I do not need anything more than a int array, I would expect to use a dictionary to count occurences. Thanks.

Comment: I understand where you are comming from. Using an array you may consider index as int key. It's pretty convenient for string. But it's not a low cost dictionary, because if you want to store for example only the Vowels how can you do it in an array? Will you add blank? Then you may think ok I can simply have a second array with with index. But when you try to implement simple operation Add/Contains/Remove specific keys. You will have to resize the array and do a lot of annoying operation that will be simple feature in a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionaries are a set of "keys" and "values" (of any types you want). You use the keys to lookup the corresponding value.

Arrays have an 'index' and a "values". They are not the same, but they both do store collections of values, just in very different ways.

In your code, you are creating an array for each of the basic 128 ascii characters. If you didn't know, all the data on your computer is stored in bits (1s and 0s), and these numbers are also used to represent letters/characters

('#' = 35;.. '3' = 51; ... 'A'=65; 'B' = 66; ... 'a' = 97; 'b' = 98, ... '~' = 126)

And when you say:

```
foreach (int c in first)
```

you are casting the char into the integer value. So when you find an 'A' in the first string, you are then incrementing the value in the array at index 65. In that way you are using the value of the character to look-up the index in the array to increment.

So what you have there is a working way to keep track of how many of each character you see, but it isn't a dictionary. You start with a placeholder for every possible character, rather than adding an element to the dictionary as you first encounter them.

Answer (score 0):

> What I don't get is how and why are my char and int arrays "smart" enough so that when I iterate over chars I can update the count of observed characters with incrementing, like it's some sort of dictionary?

Are you asking why iterating works over arrays? It's a very basic concept, you have an array, you iterate over it.

That has nothing to do with dictionaries. In fact, dictionaries aren't iterable at all (in a stable way), the `Dictionary<>` class stores the elements in an internal list to allow iteration, which is why dictionaries are relatively fat objects.

Comment: And just to be clear, there's no reason to call `ToCharArray()` in the first place, the code you wrote will work the same without it. `string` objects are also iterable over `char`.

Comment: No, more like why int array of 128 characters is kinda in and of itself a basic dictionary for ASCII table and their values (if you are just counting occurences) -

so let's say 'a' is index 97 in an int array and value is 2 ( 2 occurences). 

For ASCII purposes, index is more than "index".

If that makes sense, sorry :).

Comment: "index is more than "index"" -- no they're not, you have an integer and you index with it into the array. I don't know what else you think is happening here, but it's just basic indexing. You are however mistaking if you believe you're doing ASCII tables here, or that characters are between -128 and 127. C# uses UTF-16 strings, so chars are at least 16-bit (0 to 65535), and Unicode has code points up to 32-bit in size, and `char`s are actually just a portion of the code point.